# SQL Union Operator? Joining 2 tables with differing amount of columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to take two tables, Table A and Table B below, and trying to do a union to create a table that stacks them on top of each other as shown in the desired output below. In my attempt below, it ended up assigning nulls to everything in the 'Category' column whereas not all cases of the 'categeory' column should be null.

The tables have a common FOLDER 'ID' which is the first column and I also tried to join on this but the issue is that table A has more Folder IDs than Table B.

I want everything from both tables blended together with no duplication. Where a value exists in one table but not the other, then it should be added to a single table just like the example output below.

Table A:

```
Folder  Categeory   Subcategory Count
AA      1           A1          21
AA      1           A2          43
AB      2           A3          23
AB      3           A4          54
AC      4           A5          44
```

Table B:

```
Folder  Categeory   Subcategory Count   
AA      NULL        A6          44  
BB      NULL        A7          43
```

Desired Output:

```
Folder  Categeory   Subcategory Count
AA      1           A1          21
AA      1           A2          43
AA      **NULL**    A6          44
AB      2           A3          23
AB      3           A4          54
AC      4           A5          44
BB      **NULL**    A7          43
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT *
FROM tableB;
```

Also tried a full join in place of the union like below but resulted in some nulls that didn't make sense

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A 
FULL JOIN TABLEB B ON A.FOLDER = B.FOLDER
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original SQL seems to work for me.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run

```
WITH TABLE_A as  ( 
  SELECT 'AA' FOLDER,  1 CATEGORY, 'A1' SUB_CATEGORY,21 COUNT_SOMETHING
UNION SELECT 'AA' FOLDER,  1 CATEGORY, 'A2' SUB_CATEGORY,43 COUNT_SOMETHING
UNION SELECT 'AB' FOLDER,  2 CATEGORY, 'A3' SUB_CATEGORY,23 COUNT_SOMETHING
UNION SELECT 'AB' FOLDER,  3 CATEGORY, 'A4' SUB_CATEGORY,54 COUNT_SOMETHING
UNION SELECT 'AC' FOLDER,  4 CATEGORY, 'A5' SUB_CATEGORY,44 COUNT_SOMETHING)
,TABLE_B as  ( 
  SELECT 'AA' FOLDER,  NULL  CATEGORY, 'A6' SUB_CATEGORY,44 COUNT_SOMETHING
UNION SELECT 'BB' FOLDER,  NULL  CATEGORY, 'A7' SUB_CATEGORY,43 COUNT_SOMETHING)

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this with Common Table Expression [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
WITH Folders AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[TableA]

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[TableB]
) 
SELECT * FROM Folders
ORDER BY Folder, Subcategory
```

Comment: What benefit is there to using the CTE in this answer except for maybe readability?